# Reshape array 1D to 2D numpy by input - Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to resolve an exercise (By SoloLearn) that I need to transform 1D array to 2D array. So, the site uses 5 tests to evaluate the code, my code just passes in the first two first tests. Can someone give me a hint?

Task: Given a list of numbers and the number of rows (r), reshape the list into a 2-dimensional array. Note that r divides the length of the list evenly.

Sample Input

2

1.2 0 0.5 -1

Sample Output

[[ 1.2 0. ]

[ 0.5 -1. ]]

Me code:

```
import numpy as np

r = int(input()) #numbers of row
lst = [float(x) for x in input().split()] #numbers in array
arr = np.array(lst)
arr = np.round(arr, 2) #round to the second decimal

two_dim = np.reshape(arr, (r, 2))
print(two_dim)
```

Comment: You can pass `-1` to `numpy.reshape` to let it infer that value from the array length and remaining dimensions.

Comment: Wow It's worked! I thought this but I didn't try because I thought it won't work... Thanks, my friend!

Comment: `len(arr) // r` is fine too, if you don't want to use `-1`